# While loop not working when working with Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, while-loop

I am working with the following dataframe `dfW`(it is a sample from a much larger dataset):

```
      bank_id    x_coordinate   y_coordinate   money    time (hr)
725      725   -0.171722    -4.622425      60700    0.720254
5068    5068    0.899443     0.337507        300    1.408178
6618    6618    2.294234     1.146300      21500    1.296493
2455    2455   -0.946596     2.457585      21300    1.276988
166      166    0.687787    -2.578104      24900    1.312164
2450    2450    0.670821    -0.538727       1100    1.282857
6283    6283   -0.099760    -0.822922        600    0.728104
81        81    2.530440    -0.342033        200    1.327394
3920    3920    3.755900    -4.829356        200    0.383559
9877    9877   -2.262354    -0.245852       1700    0.357900
```

With a time limit of 3, I am trying to calculate how much money (`score`) I can extract from the banks in the df while travelling at 30 km/h from bank to bank and `df['time hr()']` the time it takes to rob a bank.
Therefore I have written the following code (it is part of a bigger function but this is enough for my question):

```
import pandas as pd 
import math
bank_list = []
time_left = 3
score = 0
dfW['money/hour'] = dfW['money']/dfW['time (hr)']

while time_left > 1:
    df30k = dfW.loc[dfW['money/hour'] > 30_000]
    df30k.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    for index, row in df30k.iloc[:-1].iterrows():
        current_position = (df30k["x_coordinate"].iloc[index], df30k["y_coordinate"].iloc[index])
        new_position = (df30k["x_coordinate"].iloc[(index + 1)], df30k["y_coordinate"].iloc[(index + 1)])
        dist_travelled = math.dist(current_position, new_position)
        travel_time = dist_travelled/30
        rob_time = df30k["time (hr)"].iloc[index]
        time_left -= travel_time
        time_left -= rob_time
        money_collected = df30k["money"].iloc[index]
        score += money_collected
        bank_id = df30k["id"].iloc[index]
        bank_list.append(bank_id)
    time_left -= df30k["time (hr)"].iloc[-1]
    score += df30k["money"].iloc[-1]
    bank_list.append(df30k["id"].iloc[-1])
    print(str(time_left)+' hr remains')
score, time_left
```

When I run the code, I get the following output:

```
2.2797462995297955 hr remains
1.559492599059591 hr remains
0.8392388985893864 hr remains
(182100, 0.8392388985893864)
```

Whereas I want the code to stop running when time_left >= 1 and then return the score at that time. I feel like I am missing something basic here but cannot figure it out. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: so you want to have the 1.55 as an asnwer?

Comment: yeah basically want it to stop after 1.55 (if that's the last time where time_left > 1)

Comment: adapt my solution to your code and let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Solution***

```
while True:

    if loop:
    ...
    # outside the if loop
    if time_left - X < 1:
    print(time_left)
    break
```

Adapt it to your code.

```
    if time_left - df30k["time (hr)"].iloc[-1] < 1:
        print((score,time_left))
        break
    time_left -= df30k["time (hr)"].iloc[-1]
    score += df30k["money"].iloc[-1]
    bank_list.append(df30k["id"].iloc[-1])
    print(str(time_left)+' hr remains')
```

**Explanation**

Within your while loop, you check if the next iteration is going to be less than 1, if so, break from the code and give me the current values.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Just had a question though, in ```if time_left - X < 1:```, what is X referring to? And would my code go inside ```if loop:```?

Comment: `X` is `df30k["time (hr)"].iloc[-1]` , you want to tell your code to test if the time_left for the next iteration is going to be less than 1 before regoing into the next iteration.

Comment: @sak made it easier for you

Comment: Hey I finally got the chance to adapt it to my code and implement it! For the specific example I gave above, this code actually works!  However when I use it for the bigger function, I get stuck in an infinite while loop but I think I can figure that out. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @sak vote up if you think the solution is ok. Regarding ur bigger data, for sure it is something different from the example, because break will take you out of the while loop

Comment: So my bigger code is basically what I shared above, repeated a couple more times for banks with different ratios. So what I shared checks banks with money/hour ratio > 30_000 and my bigger function has a couple other ranges (trying to do a greedy algorithm style where I go after banks with highest ratios first and so on) So it is the same code just repeated 2-3 more times for different ratios

Comment: @sak i understand, it might take some time but it will work

Comment: Yeah I think I should be able to solve that issue. Thank you again for your help and patience!